# Maven jetty plugin for Java EE development

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a Java EE app that uses EJB 3, JPA, JAX-RS and CDI. I included jetty maven plugin and want to specify dependencies that implement the APIs that are missing in jetty. I used the following dependency list and jetty configuration.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.3.v20150827</version>
            <configuration>
                <jettyXml>src/test/resources/jetty.xml</jettyXml>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.192</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
                    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.5.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openwebbeans-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId>
                    <version>4.7.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
                    <version>2.23.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                    <version>2.23.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Then my jetty.xml config is this

```
<Configure id ="h2" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <New id="h2Datasource" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>jdbc/h2</Arg>
      <Arg>
        <New class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
          <Set name="driverClass">org.h2.Driver</Set>
          <Set name="jdbcUrl">jdbc:h2:./target/db/testdb</Set>
          <Set name="user">sa</Set>
          <Set name="password"></Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
   </New>
 </Configure>
```

But then when I do mvn clean package jetty:run I get this exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.3.v20150827:run (default-cli) on project dip-cv-web: Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.3.v20150827:run failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.3.v20150827:run: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
```

I can provide more details if needed. Not sure what else you might find helpful to help me debug this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I could found out that when I comment out the openejb dependency it's not causing that issues above, but this is not helping me as I need ejb support. Might be that jax-rs implementation conflicts with the openejb in some way?

Answer (score 0):

You usually get "NoSuchMethodError" when you are having two different versions of the class on your class path. 
As the javax.ws.rs.core.Application class does have the getProperties() method in its JAX-RS 2 version, but not in JAX-RS 1.x.

You can get the dependency tree using following maven command

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=javax.ws.rs

 --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ language-processing ---
- +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.23.2:compile
- |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.23.2:com
- |  |  \- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
- |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.23.2:compile
- |  |  \- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
- |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.23.2:compile
- |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.23.2:compile
- |  |  |  \- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate
- |  |  \- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
- |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
- \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.23.2:compile
-    \- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.23.2:compile
-       \- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

your `jersey-container-servlet` dependency brings `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar`